# Overloading pure virtual operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, abstract-class, derived-class, pure-virtual

I have abstract class `Number` with 4 pure virtual operators (`+`,`-`,`/`,`*`). I want to make two derived classes `Integer` and `Real` and override there these operators. I don't properly understand how to declare operators. I haven't found any examples in the net similar to my situation.

My questions are:
In abstract base class `Number` my operators must return reference `Number&` or pointer `Number*`, since I can't return abstract class itself. But what should I pass as arguments ? `Number&` or `Number*` too, but I need to store number in class, should I have in my base class something like `void* num`?
Let's imagine, I have

```
class Number {
    ...
    virtual Number& operator+(const Number&) = 0;
};
```

How should I override this operator in derived class `Integer`?

Comment: Suppose you had that class hierarchy, could you give an example how you would use it? It's not clear what you really want to get in the end.

Comment: @Evg hm, something like simple custom int class.

Comment: Not sure if you're on the right way with your design... You will need to be able to add `Integer`s and `Real`s this way – but unless you have some common representation for numbers, you'll need to know about the type... On the other hand, if you had such common representation, then why not already use in Number base class?

Comment: Suppose you write `Integer(1) + Real(1.1)`. What the return type should be? This design doesn't look meaningful to me, I don't understand how it can be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ polymorphism of operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969966/c-polymorphism-of-operator-overloading)

Comment: Nah, I don't really need atm to add real+int only real+real, int+int

Comment: @Evg at the end of the story, I should be able to use operators for 2 integers, 2 reals, using pointer to base class Number.

Comment: But if you don't know about the type? `Number& n0 = ...; Number& n1 = ...; Number& n2 = n0 + n1;` – your design allows `n0` and `n1` to be of any type. And now?

Comment: E.g. Number* n= new Integer (2)

Comment: " I don't really need atm to add real+int only real+real, int+int" then why bother about virtual methods or inheritance in the first place? You dont need `Integer` and `Real` to inherit from a base class in order to enable `Integer + Integer` and `Real + Real`

Comment: I know, but my tutor insist on doing it as overriding pure virtual operator as exercising in abstract classes, but I really don't get it

Comment: maybe add that to the question because "I want to make two derived classes..." sounds as if you made that choice for some reason when actually it is a fixed constraint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know, but my tutor insist on doing it as overriding pure virtual operator as exercising in abstract classes, but I really don't get it.

Well, you can learn about two things from this:

1. How virtual functions work in general (and a custom operator is just nothing else than an ordinary function, solely calling syntax differs).
2. Virtual functions aren't the Holy Grail to solve *anything*.

The problem is that the classes `Integer` and `Real` most likely have differing internal representation – so you won't be able to do the addition/multiplication/... without knowing about the concrete type you received as second operand. Additionally, it is pretty unclear what the return type of mixed operand types should be.

> I don't really need atm to add real+int only real+real, int+int

Well, OK, we can catch this:

```
class Number
{
public:
    virtual ~Number() { } // in any case, a virtual base class should have a virtual destructor!

    // fine so far:
    virtual Number& operator+(Number const&) const = 0;
    // we are not going to change the          ^
    // own instance, so we'd rather have this operator const
    // (in contrast to operator+=)
};

class Integer : public Number
{
public:
    Integer& operator+(Number const& other) const override
    // ^ co-variant return type, so that's fine
    {
        // at very first, we make sure that we actually received
        // an instance of type Integer
        auto o = dynamic_cast<Integer const*>(&other);
        if(!o)
            // if not, throwing an exception is a good candidate
            // for error handling...
            throw std::invalid_argument("argument must be of type Integer");

        // now as we know it IS an Integer:
        return Integer(this->value + o->value); // or whatever...
        // OOPS - the returned object gets lost when the function is left...
    }
};
```

If you want to be able to add `Real`s, too, then you'd have another type cast. Assuming `Integer + Real` results in `Real`, you'd then have to change the return type back to `Number`, though.

However, yet a great problem contained: The returned object gets destroyed as soon as the function is left, so the reference returned is dangling.

We'll have to fix this by some means. References aren't suitable, though, so we might opt for a smart pointer:

```
class Number
{
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Number> operator+(Number const&) const = 0;
};

class Integer : public Number
{
    std::unique_ptr<Number> operator+(Number const& other) const override
    //                 ^
    // unfortunately, now, as ordinary struct, no co-variance possible any more
    {
        return std::make_unique<Integer>(this->value + o->value);
    }
};
```

This problem again illustrates how inappropriate the approach chosen actually is...

Comment: a milder version of your statement would be "Virtual functions aren't the Holy Grail to solve everything.", though I completely agree with what you wrote :)

Comment: You return a dangling reference here. One possible solution is to return `std::unique_ptr<Number>`.

Comment: @Evg Damn, sure, of course. Totally unused to operators returning references... Proves again how bad the imposed concept is.

Comment: God bless you, lads.

Comment: @Evg Absolutely. Don't seem to be paying attention today :(

Comment: There is no covariant types for non-pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Hm, should really get rid of those dirty quick-quick fixes that aren't real ones – or better entirely stop this stuff for today. Tomorrow's another day... Thanks anyway for pointing out.